# Using the Microsoft cognitive translate endpoint to obtain the languages information return no content

Tags: botframework

Hitting the http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html#!/default/get_GetLanguagesForTranslate endpoint using the tool provided on that web page with a valid token (and the preceeding Bearer keyword) has the tool return no content, and a result code of 0, which is not an expected result.

Doing the same operation from a curl command line does work. Used multiple browser yielded the same results on the web page. Anything broken atm ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the appid parameter to "Bearer" + " " + *[token]* ?

Beside the description it states:
"Required when Authorization header is not specified. If the Authorization header is used, leave the appid field empty else a string containing "Bearer" + " " + access token."

---

I retrieved a temporary token here: http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/oauth-token.html using an Azure Cognitive Services Translator Text API key.  And used that in the appid field to call GetLanguagesForTranslate here: http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html#!/default/get_GetLanguagesForTranslate

The results:

[image]

Comment: Hello Eric,

   I do know that the appid method works in the tool, but we do use the Authorization form in our system, which has to have an empty appid field, and use Bearer + " " + token into the authorization header. We would expect the tool to work correctly, as even sending the curl generated by that tool does yield the correct results!

Comment: Hey @PIBM, you're right... and now, I'm unable to get the appid method to work in the online tool.